# xml deserialization in c++

Tags: c++, xml, xml-deserialization

I want to write a C++ code that uses XML deserialization. Can any one please suggest an easy-to-use library for xml deserialization in c++, and a basic example code on how to deserialize an xml file with it? I tried using the CMarkup library, but it does not work for my xml documents. It does not seem to be generic enough.

Thanks!

Comment: if you have a xsd schema description of your xml document you might look at codesynthesis xsd which generates all the cpp code you need for deserialization

Answer (score 2):

+1 to TinyXML. I used it in my past projects and it works pretty fine. The library is very simple, easy to maintain and quite stable.
You do not need to compile TinyXML as a shared or static library - just add the TinyXML sources in your code and build it. As a result you will get rid of distributing any shared libraries with your program.

Answer (score 1):

I've used both [Xerces for C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) and [LibXML](http://xmlsoft.org/) in the past, and never found any major issues with either. Sample Xerces code is available [here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-3.html), and sample LibXML code is [here](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html).

While I've never tried it, I've heard some good things about [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html) too.

Comment: I've also used both Xerces, libXML and TinyXML. I found xerces a little "large" for most of my uses. TinyXML was a little slow for some cases too (though that was a long time ago, things may have improved).  I settled on libXML and have been happy with it.